# Overflow hidden - element focus uncenters stationary elements off screen

Tags: css, focus, overflow, simplemodal

I have the base of my website set up as a stationary template. The main container scrolls while everything else is meant to stay put on the screen.

The modal is 100% css controled (as seen here https://www.labnol.org/code/20083-modal-popup-css) and covers the same area as the main-container

The problem is that whenever I open a modal or click on a link that references any ID in my main-container, the screen focus jumps to center on it and and all my other stationary parts are moved upward/outward to be pushed out of view on the screen. If I close the modal the new positions of all the elements will remain in place unless I reset the whole page.

Why is this?

```
<style>
html, body {
overflow: hidden;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
</style>

<body>
  <header></header>
  <nav></nav>
  <main>
    <sidebar>
      <a href="">Modal1</a>
      <a href="">Modal2</a>
      <a href="">Modal3</a>
    </sidebar>
    <main-container>
      <div id="initialContent"></div>
      <div id="modal1"></div>
      <div id="modal1"></div>
      <div id="modal1"></div>
   </main-container>
  <main>
  <footer></footer>
<body>
```